# Calculate coordinates from coordinates, distance and an angle

Tags: java, math, latitude-longitude

I want to calculate the coordinates of a new point given an original point, a distance and an angle.

```
Position calculateDestinationPoint(Position position, double distanceInMeter, double angle) {
    double startLatitude = Math.toRadians(position.getLatitude());
    double startLongitude = Math.toRadians(position.getLongitude());
    double bearing = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double earthRadius = 6371e3;

    double angularDistance = distanceInMeter / earthRadius;

    double destinationLatitudeRadians = Math.asin(Math.sin(startLatitude) * Math.cos(angularDistance) +
            Math.cos(startLatitude) * Math.sin(angularDistance) * Math.cos(bearing));

    double destinationLongitudeRadians = startLongitude + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing) * Math.sin(angularDistance) * Math.cos(startLatitude),
            Math.cos(angularDistance) - Math.sin(startLatitude) * Math.sin(destinationLatitudeRadians));

    return new Position(Math.toDegrees(destinationLatitudeRadians), (Math.toDegrees(destinationLongitudeRadians) + 540) % 360 - 180);
}
```

Unfortunately a test for that method is not passing

```
    @Test
public void test100km90Degree() throws Exception {
    Position position = new PointCalculator().calculateDestinationPoint(new Position(0.0, 0.0), 100_000, 90);
    Assert.assertEquals(new Position(0.0, 0.89944444), position);
}
```

Log

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :Position(latitude=0.0, longitude=0.89944444)
Actual   :Position(latitude=5.506530518221826E-17, longitude=0.8993216059187716)
```

I am not sure if the logic is correct or I missed something.

PS: I got inspired by [this github repo](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy)

Comment: Dont compare doubles with equals, due to rounding they will differ by a little, like in 0.89944444 ≈ 0.89932160

Comment: Looks like you've incurred rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

The latitude looks like a rounding error, but the longitude is off by 1.37e-4, which is quite big. Where did you get the correct result and the size of the Earth? If 6371e3 is off by 1e3 then you get an error of 1.6e-4. It is more likely to be an imprecise constant than a rounding error greater than 1e-4 on doubles.

Comment: You're right with the rounding error for the longitude. 
But the latitude should still be 0.0 when I move straight to east (90°)?
I got the results form [this site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).